# How to customize styling of mat-select?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I have a custom theme and with respect to that I want to style the `mat-select` leaving the `mat-option` part as it is. I am able to change the background color of it but not able to change the `font-color`, `font-family`, `font-size` and also the `height` & `padding` like the sample one.

Can anyone help me ?
Please refer this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ycp6kc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for your reference. I want it to look like the textbox present there.

Comment: When you say "not able", what did you try?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple.

1. Create a **_material_override.css** file on root level of your project.
2. Do the overriding of styles on mat-select classes as per your requirement within this file.
3. Import this css file in the **style.css** file of your project.